# Editing jmeter saveservice.properties file using Jmeter Maven Plugin

Tags: maven, maven-3, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-maven-plugin

Is there a way to edit(add some properties to it) the Jmeter saveservice.properties file when I am invoking Jmeter using the Jmeter Maven Plugin?

Answer (score 0):

you can either copy your own version of saveservice.properties to:

```
${project.base.directory}/src/test/jmeter
```

Or you can override specific properties using the <propertiesSaveService> configuration setting like this:

```
+---+
<project>
    [...]
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                    <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jmeter</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <propertiesSaveService>
                            <HTTPSampler2>org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSampler2</HTTPSampler2>
                        </propertiesSaveService>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    [...]
</project>
+---+
```

This information is now available on the project wiki at https://github.com/Ronnie76er/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Modifying-Properties